# Displaying page hits in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal site which allows users to sign up and add their own content. I am trying to create something that emails users every week and shows them statistics like how many people viewed your content etc. I have turned on the statistics module and checked on count content views. I moved the popular content block into the correct region but it will not show me the number of hits only the most popular content pages. I would like to be able to show the number of hits. I was also wondering if there is a programatically way to print the number of page hits so I could do it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the statistics module's [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/). You can use [statistics_get($nid)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/function/statistics_get/7) function to get total count of views of a node.

Answer (score 0):

try Google Analytics Reports module. Statistics module has big impact on performance because of the huge db writes.